# SQL BETWEEN not working properly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using Microsoft SQL Server

I am  trying to use the following sql command  to get the records between First_Name "Nilsen" and "Ram"

```
select * from persons where First_Name between 'Nilsen' and 'Ram'
```

but i am getting the output as two records with first names "nilsen" and "ram"; not the records between these records.

In another command, i tried doing similar thing with Last names.

```
select * from persons where Last_Name between 'Johan' and 'Chandra'
```

this command shows just a blank persons table.

Please tell me its not working properly.

Comment: Could you please tell what did you expect the query to return?

Comment: BETWEEN in SQL server probably works fine, but we need more information about what you are doing, what you're seeing, and what you expected, before we can tell you what you did wrong. Now, it *could* be that there is a bug in BETWEEN, but the chance of you either using it wrong, or not understanding the results, has a *much* higher chance, so let's start with that.

Comment: notice he's using first_name when expecting last_name :) It's no doubt working properly, just not as expected.

Comment: @jwenting, yeah, "Nilsen" is a last name, and "Johan" is a first name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    persons
WHERE   First_Name between 'Nilsen' and 'Ram'
```

will return all entries with `First_Name` alphabetically between `Nilsen` and `Ram` (like `Oscar`, `Rachel` or `Norbert`)

This query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    persons
WHERE   Last_Name between 'Johan' and 'Chandra'
```

will never return anything since `Johan` is greater than `Chandra` (i. e. goes later in alphabetical order).

**Update:**

Just a wild guess: if you want to match something like `Nilsen Hermenegild J. P. Ram, Jr.`, you need to use this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    persons
WHERE   FirstName LIKE '%Nilsen%Ram%
```

Comment: +1 exactly what I meant but wasn't able to clarify as succinctly (and fast, and proper formatted, and... oh well).

Comment: oops...i forgot that it searches in alphabatical order.

Comment: @vatspoo: could you please tell what string did you expect to return? We are intrigued!

Comment: I am learning sql. i used between clause but forgot that it returns the records with name alphabetically between the specified values and expected the output as all the records specified in the table between those values. sorry for the confusion :(

Answer (score 1):

This is how BETWEEN works, from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa225976%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

> BETWEEN returns TRUE if the value of
>   test_expression is greater than or
>   equal to the value of begin_expression
>   and less than or equal to the value of
>   end_expression.

so

```
select * from persons where First_Name between 'Nilsen' and 'Ram'
```

should return records with first names 'Nilsen' and 'Ram', plus the records between.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, try this:

```
select * from persons where lower(First_Name) between 'nilsen' and 'ram'
```